# VS C++ overload as function for references to temporary objects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.8.1 C++ with /std:c++latest.  I wrote code that uses references to temporary objects to create formatted output.  I know that this is problematic, but it works nicely so far.

The following code compiles OK (with `cl /c /W4 /std:c++latest referenceBinding.cpp`):

```
struct format {
    format& operator<<(int i);
};

void wusel() {
    format() << 1;
}
```

Unfortunately, I would like to have the overloads as functions, not members, so I can easily add new overloads.  However, *this* code

```
struct format {
    format& operator<<(int i);
};
format& operator<<(format& f, int i);
//format& operator<<(format&& f, int i);

void wusel() {
    format() << 1;
}
```

causes an error:

```
referenceBinding.cpp(16): error C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand     operand of type 'format' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
referenceBinding.cpp(12): note: could be 'format &operator <<(format &,int)'
referenceBinding.cpp(16): note: while trying to match the argument list '(format, int)'
```

Only when I add the second (outcommented) rvalue-reference overload, it works without complaints.  I'd like to understand, why?

BTW: I know that the `/Zc:referenceBinding-` option turns the error into a warning.

Comment: Probably a bug. It compiles from msvc19.14 at least.

Answer (score 1):

In your function

```
void wusel() {
    format() << 1;
}
```

the return value of `format()` is an rvalue. It can't bind to an lvalue reference.

If `format` doesn't need to be modified, you can use a `const format&` to accept both rvalues and lvalues, since const reference can bind to both.

```
format& operator<<(const format& f, int i);
```

Another option could be to make `operator<<` a template and use forwarding references, then it would detect at compile time if you are passing an rvalue or lvalue and use the one suited for the call.

```
template <typename T>
format& operator<<(T&& f, int i);
```

With the template solution you would most likely want to restrict the template to only be picked out as an overload if `T = format`. You can do that with SFINAE.

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_save_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, format>>>
format& operator<<(T&& f, int i);
```